# How to re-use models between node.js projects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, project-management, dry

I have two node.js (more specifically, express.js) projects. Lets consider "project A" which is the main project, and "project B" which is an "ad-hoc" (for a certain purpose) project. Project B needs project A models.

How to re-use project A's models wisely without repeating code? (And how is it working practically, in terms of how the two projects are arranged?)

Thanks.

Comment: Two different projects warrant two different sets of models. Even if you are using the exact same code, you can never be sure that both will use the same code in future too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A decent approach to deal with this would be to separate it as a module you can install using `npm`. (You can install private packages with it)

This would allow you to easily manage any dependencies your library has. You can define them into the `package.json` file, and whenever a project needs the library, you simply install it and `npm` deals with the dependencies.